# strange behaviour in [array] Calling Address method

Tags: powershell

I've tested this on Win XP and Windows Server 2008 R2 in Powershell 2.0:

```
$a = 1,2,3,4 # a simple [object[]] but any other Type is good
```

if I do:

```
$a.addres()
```

the return error is (correctly):

**`Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'addres'.`**

But if I do:

```
$a.address()
```

the error is:

**`Cannot find an overload for "Address" and the argument count: "0".`**

But doing:

```
$a.address(2)
```

close powershell console with an `'Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH'`

starting from that `[system.array]` has not a method called `address` how powershell try to call an existing method?

Comment: Interesting.  On V3 I get this error `PS>  $a.address(2)
Exception calling "Address" with "1" argument(s): "Operation could destabilize the runtime."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System.Array] has .Get, .Set and .Address methods that are available via the .Net runtime but are not normally used in Powershell code. Have a look at this StackOverflow [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555769/where-can-i-find-information-on-the-get-set-and-address-methods-for-multidimens):

Comment: THank you! I didn't found this SO answer! Now all is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted this as a bug a while back. They fixed it in V3 with the exception message Keith posted ( could destabilize the runtime )

https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/561865/powershell-crashes-when-calling-address-method-on-object-array