# Powershell showing wrong output for JSON-object and ADDRESS-property

Tags: json, powershell, convertfrom-json, member-enumeration

I am currently struggling to convert a JSON-string into an array of objects and to GENERALLY handle the properties/attributes of each object.

Here is a simple demo, that shows that e.g. the attribute "address" seems to be a bit special:

```
cls
$json = '[{"id":"1","address":"1"},{"id":"2","address":"2"}]'
$list = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$list.id                      # OK
$list.address                 # gives a weired result - is this a bug?
$list.GetEnumerator().address # that works
```

This is the output:

```
1
2

OverloadDefinitions                                                                                        
-------------------                                                                                        
System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Address(int )  

1
2
```

As you can see, I need to add ".GetEnumerator()" to get the correct "address"-values.

Is this the expected? Should I ALWAYS use the ".GetEnumerator()" to be safe?

Comment: `Address` resolves to the `Address` property of the array contained in `$list` - do `$list|% address` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$list` is an *array* (collection), using something like **`$list.id` performs [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)**; that is, the `.id` property is automatically accessed *on each element*, and the resulting values are returned as an array (`[object[]]`)<sup>[1]</sup>.

However, **if the array / collection type *itself* has a member by that name (a property or method), it *takes precedence***, which is what happened in your case: .NET arrays have an `.Address` method (that is added by the runtime - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2555769/45375)), and that is what preempted accessing the *elements'* `.Address` property.

(What you saw was PowerShell's representation of the method's signature (overload), which is what you get when you access a method by name only, without actually calling it by appending (`(...)`); try `'foo'.ToUpper`, fo instance.)

<sup>That PowerShell provides no distinct operator syntax to distinguish between direct member access and member-access enumeration is the subject of [GitHub issue #7445](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7445), but the existing behavior is unlikely to change.</sup>

The most efficient way to work around that problem is to use the **PSv4+ [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#foreach)**  array method, which always targets the collection's *elements*:

```sh
$list = '[{"id":"1","address":"1"},{"id":"2","address":"2"}]' | ConvertFrom-Json

$list.ForEach('address')
```

**Caveat**: If you're running ***Windows PowerShell*** and `$list` can situationally just result in a *single* `pscustomobject` rather than an *array*, you must **enclose `$list` in `@(...)`**, the array-subexpression operator, to ensure that the `.ForEach()` method is available. This is a **`[pscustomobject]`-specific *bug*** (given that even single objects should consistently have a `.ForEach()` method), which has been **fixed in PowerShell (Core) 6+**.

```sh
# @(...) is necessary in Windows PowerShell only.
@($list).ForEach('address')
```

Note:

- Technically, this returns a `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[PSObject]]` collection, but in most cases you can use it like a regular `[object[]]` PowerShell array.
- Unlike with member-access enumeration, a collection instance is also returned if there's only *one* element in the input collection (rather than returning that one element's property value as-is, the way member-access enumeration does).

---

In **PSv3-** you can use the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, or `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`:

```sh
$list | ForEach-Object address # PSv2: | ForEach-Object { $_.address }
# OR
$list | Select-Object -ExpandProperty address
```

---

<sup>[1] If there's only *one* element in the collection, its property value is returned as-is, not wrapped in a (single-element) array, which is the same logic that is applied when collecting *pipeline* output in a variable. That this logic may be unexpected in the context of member-access enumeration, which is an *expression* context, is being discussed in [GitHub issue #6802](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6802).</sup>